# Speeding up a SPARQL query with multiple filters?

Tags: rdf, sparql, semantic-web, dbpedia

Is there a way to speed up a SPARQL query like this one?

```
PREFIX geo: <http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#>         
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>           
PREFIX dbpedia-owl: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>             
PREFIX xsd:  <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>               
SELECT ?subject ?label ?lat ?long ?abstract                    
WHERE {                                                        
  ?subject geo:lat ?lat      .                                   
  ?subject geo:long ?long    .                                   
  ?subject rdfs:label ?label .                                   
  ?subject dbpedia-owl:abstract ?abstract .                      
  FILTER(
          xsd:float(?lat)  - 45.9634177 <= 0.05 && 45.9634177 - xsd:float(?lat)  <= 0.05 
       && xsd:float(?long) - 10.90836034 <= 0.05 && 10.90836034 - xsd:float(?long) <= 0.05 
  ).                                                           
  FILTER langMatches( lang(?label), "EN" ).   
  FILTER langMatches( lang(?abstract), "EN" ).                       
}
```

Comment: Is this something you're running against the public DBpedia endpoint?  Do you have any idea about which things are making it run slower than you'd like?  Are any parts non-vital (e.g., removing all the filters would make everything faster, I'm sure, but would probably give you results that you don't want, too :))?

Comment: One particular thing that might also speeds things up is restricting `?subject` to a certain type, e.g. if you're only interested in towns, add 

     `?subject a <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Town>`

Comment: How slowly is this query running?  When I run it on the DBpedia's SPARQL endpoint, it seems to return relatively quickly.